# i wish to start "out" animation of a layer (in revslider) via js script

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I wish to start "out" animation of a layer (in hero slider) via js script​ is it even possible?​
I have layer named lr192 and i would like to start an "out" animation, but i cant find any info on how to any-ware.

Comment: Or even a way to reset the slider to initial state ;/

Comment: Question is not clear, could you please add a image and more details.